# Passport.js practical for simple login

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, jwt

I'm designing my user authentication system using Node.js/Express, and as I've been searching the web for authentication strategies, I noticed that a lot of developers recommend passport.js for helping with authentication.

My authentication will only ever use a username/password strategy with JSON web tokens.  Under that assumption, it seems like I have to manage the entire authentication myself: I check the username and password against the database, and I check and attach JWTs.  It seems like Passport only wraps my work inside it's own functions.

With only a username/password strategy, what use is Passport? What does Passport provide in this scenario that is of any real benefit over me just performing the authentication without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passport give you more flexibility and scalability. Now, you need one specific strategy, but in future you can add additional or remove old one. Using modules like passport you cause that your application code is independent of some processes. It is almost like dependency injection, you inject strategy in opposite to hardcode this.

I thing, that good application should have as much as possible functions/modules, that allow to inject polices/strategies. Separate modules is also nodejs/express style.

If you code your authentication in same style, then it is super (but why reinventing the wheel).

Using passport you can inherit from base Strategy and create new one strictly for your needs and use it with other strategies.

Comment: Good points, but I don't believe they are strong enough to warrant dealing with another module.  If the only reasons to use Passport would be to 1) have more modular code and 2) more flexibility for possible future additions to authentication strategies, then 1) using Passport to simply modularize is only increasing my codebase and dependencies and 2) I can easily switch to Passport when I need to cross that bridge.

Comment: I like your point of view too. I have no more arguments in favor of Passport. Sometimes i also choose own solutions, but i belive that most of the time arguments in my answer are correct.

Answer (score 0):

## Never. Ever. Implement. Your. Own. Security. Framework

Unless you actually want to implement a **framework** and you have all the resources in the world to do that, all the required knowledge and the key people ( like OWASP ) & etc etc.

## Use existing lib for your project

Use a library, or a framework, that's open source and battle tested. Yes it will not be perfect and will have limitations. Yes it may not be the most secure code ever. BUT it will be much better than your own, especially if you're starting from scratch.

Then follow best practices for CSRF, XSS, DDoS & other kind of attack prevention.